# cloned to SSD from HDD and black screen after splash

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd

Just copied data with easeUS partition, to SSD from HDD. Windows 7 boots from hdd but with ssd after the windows splash screen, I see the mouse pointer which I can move.First time after cloning I did the system recovery. What may be the problem.

after a while,

Now I wanted to go back and use original HDD for cloning again. even that had the same problem. and when I try to repair with disc, it shows loading file and after that black screen (no language and recovery selection page), how ever, if I go back to SSD , the system repair works.

So, I tried to play with boot recoreds.

So, did

```
fixmbr
fixboot
rebuildBCD
```

I got message

```
Please wait, since this may take a while...

Successfully scanned Windows installations.
Total identified Windows installations: 0
The operation completed successfully.
```

Now, 
with `disk part`, made it `active` and repeated those steps again, 
and now the message is

```
"disk read error occurred, ctrl+al+del to restart"
```

back to the HDD, I can not even get to the repair window, I even tried only DVD, get to that scree and plugged in hdd, but no help

every time, I unplugged any other drives, and only one monitor. 
I tried ubuntu live CD and works fine

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with a WD1600AABS: it would not boot and I would receive exactly the same message, even after I tried do reinstall Windows XP on it. **Beware that what I did erased the MBR, so I lost my partitions table, consequently I lost access to what was stored in the drive.**

To fix that, I:

- Created a bootable USB flash drive with FreeDOS using Rufus.
- Downloaded HDAT2, the [standalone executable](http://www.hdat2.com/files/hdat2_50.exe).
- Set my SATA controller to Compatible/IDE in BIOS.
- In HDAT2, I select my hard drive, went to Device Tests Menu > Wipe Device Menu
- Selected "Wipe device with WRITE", S to Setup, and I set "6. Last Sector Number" to 128, and went back with ESC.
- Pressed ENTER, and the warning can be ignored because I set it to stop at de 128th sector. Y for Yes, then.
- It will finish fast.
- Now you can do whatever you want without any problem.

**Since I overwrote the MBR, I lost the data. I assume that you have a backup of your data or knows how to use data recovery software.**

Comment: wow, thank you,  an answer after more than a month, have an upvote, however, because I solved it differently, I cannot test and verify it as answer.